# Nagios NRPE is not reading custom python plugin that is running fine from the command line

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, nagios, debian-stretch, nrpe

I have created a custom plugin for NRPE in Python 3. The script runs as expected when I run it from the command line as root and when I run it as nagios user. (I had a problem before when the nagios user didn't have permissions, but I fixed this is the sudoers file). I have an Arduino Uno taking input from a wind sensor and outputting the speed as type float to the serial monitor. The python script on my Raspberry Pi (os similar to debian 9) is reading the serial output and determining if the speed is in a specific range and then exiting with the respective code. Here's the python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import serial
import sys
import time

port = '/dev/ttyACM0'
baud = 9600

ser = serial.Serial(port,baud)
time.sleep(1) #allow time to connect with serial
def read_sensor():
    i = 0
    MPH_list = [] #used to find average of wind speed
    while i < 5:
        try:
            speed = ser.readline()
            speed = speed.decode("utf-8")
            MPH_list.append(float(speed))

            i += 1
        except:
            print('Failed to read Serial Monitor')
            sys.exit(3) #unknown exit status

    avgMPH = sum(MPH_list) / len(MPH_list) #average wind speed
    print("%.2f MPH | 'Wind Speed'=%.2f" % (avgMPH,avgMPH)) #speed | performance data

    if avgMPH < float(sys.argv[1]):
        exit_code = 0
    elif avgMPH >= float(sys.argv[1]) and avgMPH < float(sys.argv[2]):
        exit_code = 1
    elif avgMPH >= float(sys.argv[2]):
        exit_code = 2
    else:
        exit_code = 3

    return exit_code

sys.exit(read_sensor())
```

When I have the code as above, I get the following response in Nagios: 
[image: Wrong Output]

But when I change from `float(sys.argv[1])` to `1.00` it outputs correctly as: [image: Correct Output]

I need to  be able to use sys.argv[] so I can pass in arguments from Nagios.

For some reason it is always exiting with a '1'(warning) error code and never entering the if statement when run from the nagios server. When I run the program from the command line, it works perfect.

The output should look something like: `0.08 MPH | 'Wind Speed'=0.08` where everything after the pipe is ignored in Nagios because it goes to create the perf data graph.

Here are some other things that may help:
nrpe.cfg command defenition:

```
command[check_MPH]=/usr/bin/sudo /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_MPH.py $ARG1$ $ARG2$
```

command line sent from nagios:

```
$USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -t 30 -c $ARG1$ $ARG2$
```

where $ARG1$ is 'check_MPH' and $ARG2$ is -a'-w 1.00 -c 15.00'

Comment: I am actually not getting any error messages, just the wrong output in Nagios. The number is correct, but it is saying "warning" when it should say "OK".

Comment: ok, thanks. I see the pictures are necessary. I'll try add them into your post.